# Git annex installation on Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-annex

I have installed **git** and **git-annex** on my Windows 8 to use with git bash. Git is ok, but git bash could not find git annex at first. I restarted my computer and now when it turns on a message pops up saying it cannot find `git-annex-autostart.vbs`. However the file is indeed at the path the start up script is looking for (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Answer found: just had to find `git-annex.exe` (look for the `cmd` folder under your `git` installation) and add to PATH:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files\ \\(x86\\)/Git/cmd/./
```